# Change App behavior in low/high end Wp7 devices

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I am going to implement the always running animation that will consume memory and CPU usage too much. Since in low end devices(256 MB RAM, like LUMIA 510) ui will hang some time.
So decided to run animation only in high memory devices (more than 512 MB Ram  like, 710, radar, 820 etc). this is can be done by fetching device total memory .

```
DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceTotalMemory");
```

Is this kind of behavior is acceptable in Market place.? please clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way to detect a 256 MB device using `DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationWorkingSetLimit")` [described at the Nokia Developer portal](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Best_practice_tips_for_delivering_apps_to_Windows_Phone_with_256_MB). The idea is ok, I do the same in a few apps.

Answer (score 2):

Why would this not be? You're simply performing an action depending on the memory-size of the device. This has nothing to do with validating the app as working consistently and following those rules of the Marketplace.

Comment: whether MSFT wont reject just because of app is not consistent in all devices.?